# Muti-page Form Submission, how to avoid form data changes in hidden fields using firebug or html inspect tools

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a 5 page form submission scenario, where in first page once the form is submitted the data submitted in page 1 will be shown in page 2 along with some other user inputs.
So in page 5 the actual transaction happen and the data is persisted to data base.

But using the inspect tools, a user can change the data that was submitted in between pages.
How can i avoid this data change.

I have gone through the ways by encoding data in javascript and store incrementally the critical data in session once the submit in pages are done.

Is there anyway apart from this.

Comment: You can sign data on server using some private key. User submits form 1. Server signs data using private key then inits form 2 with data and signature (one hidden field more). User changes old data using some tool and submits form 2. Server checks incoming data using available signature and public key and rejects it.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko, i have gone through that approach already as mentioned in the question. This approach has a overhead of encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: I was talking about signing data not encrypting/decrypting. So you will be able to detect if the data were modified. Anyway if you think the overhead of signing is significant this method wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You cant prevent client side changes in your html, css or javascript. You can hold results of previous forms in user session. If user change input value, you still have server side copy of original informations.

Comment: have mentioned this approach in my question as well, this approach is a bottle neck when there are many concurrent users.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to submit your form using CURL. This makes sure that all the form data are generated on the server side.
Read more about CURL here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php.

Comment: The answer is not related to the question asked. I have to gather information from the end user.